# Flat file splitting in Biztalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have txt file with following data:

```
1, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
2, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
3, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
4, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
5, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
6, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
7, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
8, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
9, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
10, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
11, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
12, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
13, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
14, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
15, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
16, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
17, Shailender, Singh, test@test.com, 98799, 5000, New Delhi, Delhi, India
```

Consider there are 20 records in the txt file in above format.

Now I need to create multiple txt file out of the above file  with max 7 records in each txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard flat-file wizard to produce your schema, assuming an unlimited (Unbound) number of records.

Then, manually change the Max Occurs attribute of your 'Line' node (not the root node) from 'Unbounded' to '7'.  BizTalk will split the **inbound** document into groups of at most 7 records.